# Opening a new screen on button click using Kivy Python

Tags: python, kivy

I have a screen(HomePge) with several buttons. I want another screen(OneMin) to be displayed when related buttons is clicked.

this is my codes:

main.py:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from libs.components.one_min import OneMin
from libs.screens.home_page import HomePage


class GeoRS(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.load_all_kv_files()
        return HomePage()

    def load_all_kv_files(self):
        Builder.load_file('libs/screens/home_page.kv')

    def on_start(self):
        self.root.dispatch('on_enter')    
if __name__== "__main__":
    GeoRS().run()
```

home_page.py:

```
import requests
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
import json
from libs.components.free_courses import Posts


class HomePage(MDScreen):

    def on_enter(self):
        self.posts()

    def posts(self):
        data = requests.get('my site post url').json()
        for post in data:
            # do somethings
    def on_start(self):
        self.root.dispatch('on_enter')

    def switch_screen(self, *args):
        # how can i switch screen???
```

home_page.kv:

```
<HomePage>:
    MDBoxLayout:
        padding: '5dp'
        adaptive_height: True
        
        MDIconButton:
            icon: 'bell-ring'
            on_release : app.switch_screen() # on release to switch
```

screen

```
        MDLabel:
            text: 'title'
            halign: "center"
            valign: "center"

        MDIconButton:
            icon: "message-bulleted"
```

I want to open a new screen when the first MDIconButton is clicked in home_page.kv
for example open this screen:

one_min.py

```
class OneMin(MDScreen):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text='a')
```

one_min.kv

```
<OneMin>:
    name: 'oneMin'
    padding: '5dp'
    adaptive_height: True

    MDLabel:
        text: 'hello'
        halign: "center"
        valign: "center"
        font_size: 25
```

Comment: You need to use a `ScreenManager`. See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-2.0.0/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html).

Comment: @John Anderson. when i use screenManager it raise this error: File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 726, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
 KeyError: 'on_enter'